# how can I modify a build-In model inside keras applications

Tags: keras

I need to get several outputs from several layers from `keras model` instead of getting the output from the last layer.

I know how to adjust the code according to what I need, but don't know how I can use it within `keras application`. I meant how can I import it then. Do I need to infall the `setup.py` at `keras-application` again. I did so but nothing happen. My changes doesn't applied. Is there any different way to get the outputs from different layer within the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the solution was so simple, you need just to call the output of specified layer.

```
new_model= tf.keras.Model(base_model.input, base_model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
```